# Missing build.xml when creating project with ClickStart?

Tags: build, jboss7.x, cloudbees

I am using Eclipse EE version and CloudBees plugin to create a ClickStart JBoss 7 project. However, I am not very familiar with the EE version of Eclipse, and used Netbeans to edit my JSP.

Then I used CloudBees SDK to run and deploy my new project but it failed (the command prompt):

> D:\Personel\Java EE\HelloCloudBees>bees run
>
> ERROR: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Personel\Java
>   EE\HelloCloudBees\build.xml (The system cannot find the file
>   specified)

I found no build.xml file in my folder. How can I create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bees run command expect an ant-based project structure, so the build.xml. As [documented](https://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK)

> CloudBees project commands are only available for applications
>   generated using the Bees wizard (on the web), built using the
>   CloudBees SDK style.

This is more or less some legacy stuff, as is now superseded by ClickStart. Equivalent command would be bees app:run but require your app to first be packaged as a WAR and only support the default tomcat6 runtime. So for your specific use-case would be simpler to package and deploy on a local JBoss 7 server. To deploy on RUN@Cloud, use bees app:deploy or just git push and let DEV@Cloud Jenkins build and deploy for you (assuming you created app with a clickstart).

Also, there's no need to use Eclipse if you're familiar with NetBeans.

Comment: When I use CloudBees sdk to download the project created with ClickStart (on web), neither Eclipse nor Netbeans could understand its type (Java EE). Now I am working with Netbeans, by creating Netbeans's Java EE project, and can only deploy the war file. What about the Entity Beans?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out maven?If yes you can download it and then use mvn eclipse:eclipse and then you can import your project in your workspace using eclipse import capabilities.File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project...you point to the file where your pom.xml file is..and is imported. Take into accoutn m2eclipse plugin in eclipse must be installed prior.

regards
\n\m

Comment: Sorry, have never used Maven. I was only taught Java EE applications programming based on Tomcat and JBoss in my university.